# $\lim_{(x,y,z) \to (0,0,0)} \frac{ xy + yz + zx }{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}$ with epsilon delta

Tags: real-analysis, limits

$$\lim_{(x,y,z) \to (0,0,0)} \frac{ xy + yz + zx }{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}=0 $$
The problem I have is with the manipulation.  I am not able to proceed with the epsilon delta approach.

Comment: What is your candidate limit?

Comment: hi. i really don't know what a candidate limit is

Comment: Usually, you have such problems presented  as "prove the following limit $\lim_{X\to A} f(X) = L$". Do you have any possible candidates for what $L$ might be?

Comment: Th candidate limit is 0

Comment: no, just say no to questions like this, it has no constructive value. The entire body of theory was developed so we don't ask these things.

Answer (score 4):

You can first estimate the difference $|f(x,y,z) - L|$, where $f$ is the function in the argument of the limit and $L=0$ is the canditate limit.

Since $|xy| \leq \frac{1}{2} (x^2+y^2)$, and similar inequalities hold for $|yz|$ and $|zx|$, you get
$$
|f(x,y,z) - L| = |f(x,y,z)| \leq \frac{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}} = 
\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}
$$
for every $(x,y,z)\neq (0,0,0)$.

Now you can easily seen that, given $\epsilon > 0$, it is enough to choose $\delta = \epsilon$ in the definition of limit.

Comment: hi. thank you for answering . the inequality you used was unknown to me .

Comment: is there a particular derivation for that inequality or we just have to memorize it?

Comment: @joeylang From $0 \leq (x \pm y)^2$

Answer (score 0):

Let $u=(x,y,z)$ and $v=(y,z,x)$. Then, by Cauchy-Schwarz:

$|xy+<z+zx| \le x^2+y^2+z^2$, hence, if $(x,y,z)  \ne (0,0,0)$:

$|f(x,y,z)| \le (x^2+y^2+z^2)^{1/2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Polar coordinates:

$x = rsin(\theta)cos(\phi)$;

$y =rsin(\theta)sin(\phi)$;

$z=rcos(\theta).$

Substituting:

$\frac{xy + yz + zx}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}} =$

$\frac{r^2(sin(\theta))^2 (1/2)sin(2\phi)}{r} +$

$\frac{r^2(1/2)sin(2\theta)sin(\phi)}{r} + $

$\frac{r^2(1/2)sin(2\theta)cos(\phi)}{r} $.

$\\ $

$0 \le r$;  $\,0 \le \theta \le π$,  $\, 0 \le \phi \le 2π$:

Let $L = 0$,  $\epsilon \gt 0$, and

$ \delta = (2/3)\epsilon$.

$r \lt \delta$  implies:

$|r(sin(\theta))^2(1/2)sin(2\phi) + $

$r(1/2)sin(2\theta)sin(\phi) +$

$r(1/2)sin(2\theta)cos(\phi) - 0 |$

$ \le r/2 +r/2 +r/2  =(3/2)r \lt \epsilon$.

(Using triangle inequality).